# Mapping derived ViewModels to base class View in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a base ViewModel and associated View. I also have multiple derived ViewModels from the base ViewModel, but I'd like to use the base View for display.

Base ViewModel and View:

- vm: `MyCompany.MyApp.Modules.Wizard.ViewModels.WizardViewModel`
- vw: `MyCompany.MyApp.Modules.Wizard.Views.WizardView`

Derived from `WizardViewModel`:

- vm: `MyCompany.MyApp.Modules.NewSpec.ViewModels.NewSpecViewModel : WizardViewModel`
- vw: (map to `MyCompany.MyApp.Modules.Wizard.Views.WizardView`)
- vm: `MyCompany.MyApp.Modules.NewSpec.ViewModels.NewMaterialViewModel : WizardViewModel`
- vw: (map to `MyCompany.MyApp.Modules.Wizard.Views.WizardView`)

I think this should be possible using the mapping in [ViewLocator or ViewModelLocator](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Handling%20Custom%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation) or [NameTransformer](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20NameTransformer), but I haven't figured it out yet.

I am using the [Gemini Framework](https://github.com/tgjones/gemini) with [Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) v1.5.2 (I plan on upgrading to v2 soon).

Here is one of the things I have tried:

```
public class NewSpecViewModel : WizardViewModel
{
    // ...
    static NewSpecViewModel()
    {
        // Escape the '.' for the regular expression
        string nsSource = typeof(NewSpecViewModel).FullName.Replace(".", @"\.");
        string nsTarget = typeof(WizardViewModel).FullName;
        nsTarget = nsTarget.Replace("WizardViewModel", "Wizard");
        // nsSource = "MyCompany\\.MyApp\\.Modules\\.NewSpec\\.ViewModels\\.NewSpecViewModel"
        // nsTarget = "MyCompany.MyApp.Modules.Wizard.ViewModels.Wizard"
        ViewLocator.AddTypeMapping(nsSource, null, nsTarget);
    }
    // ...
}
```

P.S. I know there are existing Wizard frameworks ([Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wizard&referringTitle=Home), [Avalon Wizard](http://avalonwizard.codeplex.com/), etc), but I don't want to add another 3rd party assembly and the Extended WPF Toolkit Wizard wasn't working properly.

P.P.S. I also want to use this style of base ViewModel/View mapping elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's [a link] (https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/398456) to right way to do this.

EDIT: Since codeplex is shutting down, here is the code from the discussion:

```
var defaultLocator = ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType;
ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) =>
{
    var viewType = defaultLocator(modelType, displayLocation, context);
    while (viewType == null && modelType != typeof(object))
    {
        modelType = modelType.BaseType;
        viewType = defaultLocator(modelType, displayLocation, context);
    }
    return viewType;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late... 
but there is an option to bind the `ViewModel` to a view directly, and maybe this helps others.

I would also append this binding to the base classes constructor. The following works for me:

```
public abstract class WizardViewModel {
    protected WizardViewModel() {
        // this --> points the child class
        ViewModelBinder.Bind(this, new WizardView(), null);
    }
}
```

With this, each child now uses the `WizardView` (without any additional programming in the child class).

```
public class NewSpecViewModel : WizardViewModel {}
```

Comment: I think this works in some cases, but be careful with it.

In this case the ViewModel must be constructed on the UI thread, becaus otherwiese the View can't get initialized.