# Where did Caliburn.Micro Codeplex discussions go?

Tags: github, migration, caliburn.micro, codeplex

A lot of links in SO point to discussions that were in https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions

(For example this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442704/125400)

When CM moved to github, did they migrate any of the discussions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it was ported over to github. I don't believe that github offers anything where that kind of discussion could meaningfully be ported into.

There is however a solution, the Internet Archive does have an archive of the discussion linked in the stack overflow discussion you linked to [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121117025446/https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/398456)